# Sign ERC20 transaction by wallet A and broadcast by wallet B

Tags: web3js, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets, ethers.js

I have 2 wallets: wallet A and wallet B where wallet A holds some amount of an ERC20 token.

I would like to be able to transfer some of those ERC20 tokens from wallet A to wallet B in a way that wallet B pays all the gas fees.

I do not want to use the 'approve' function of the ERC20 contract since invoking the 'approve' function involves a gas payment by wallet A (imagin wallet A has 0 ETH, it only holds ERC20).

As I see it wallet A should sign a raw transaction of a smart contract call (calling the '*transfer*' function of the ERC20 contract) and wallet B should broadcast it and therefore  pay for the gas.

Does this make sense?
If wallet B broadcasts transaction which is signed by wallet A, will the *msg.sender* (inside the contract's '*transfer*' function) be recognized as wallet A who singed this transaction?

Assuming this is how it works, how do I create, sign and broadcast a smart contract call using [Ethers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers) (preferred with Node.js/Typescript)?

Comment: This can be achieved if the ERC20 token that you're working with, supports a [permit function](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612).

Comment: @SohamZemse I wrote that I do not want to use the 'approve' function of the ERC20 contract and explained why.

Comment: That's currently not possible in ethereum to make a CALL such that msg.sender is someone else. However there are some EIPs that propose ways to do that. One of them is AUTHCALL (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3074)

Comment: Btw I meant the "permit" function and not "approve". Wallet A signs a EIP712 permit, and Wallet B broadcasts it. Currently you might use this workaround, until when we get AUTHCALL or something else.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I can't use EIP712 since ERC20 contracts don't support it. Have you heard of relayers? https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/sending-gasless-transactions